# Best gear progression for Wanderer class

Tags: dark-souls

I have recently started Dark souls with a Wanderer class and I am wondering what the best gear progression is for Wanderers. I am playing with dexterity and strength as my focus.

So basically I want to know what gear I should be wearing through the game (e.g to begin with wanderer set with scimitar then from there I should equip thief set etc).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of this, but I've read that the Wanderer set is one of the better armor sets when you get it leveled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dexterity and strength builds the best 3 weapons to overpower yourself fairly early in the game would be A) Battleaxe (hollow warrior drop) B) Winged Spear (Item found on Corpse near the entrance to the catacombs) C) Drake Sword (Acquried by shooting the Red Dragons Tail around 20 times with arrows) as for Armour the first one to acquire would be the Leather Armour Set in Darkroot Basin. If youre lucky you may be able to set yourself up nicely for later on in the game by defeating the Black Knight with the Halbird and one with the Sword and Sheild to get the Black Knight Sheild and Sword as well as the Halbird which is by far one of the coolest weapons in the game in my oppinion you have to have good luck to get them with your item drop rate increased.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: I have managed to get a black knight sword, shield and greatsword but no halberd, is the eagle shield better to use? As for armour I am up to Sens Fortress, anything in particular I would need there?

Comment: I wasn't aware of the eagle shield. but the gold covetous serpent ring is a must find in Sens Fortress

Comment: theres also a ring called "Ring of Steel Protection". If you like feeling safe behind a lot of armour this ring increases your physical defence considerably and you'll find a merchant if you jump across the broken bridge near the golem that is dropping the bolders

Comment: does my answer fit your question or do you still have queeries?

Comment: Also another thing I forgot was the merchant in the Undead Burg buy the residence key, bottomless box and chain mail armour, kill him and you gain a uchigatana, an old favourite on the souls games :P